# Razor Pages Template Project Routing Does not Work out of the box

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I created ASP.NET Core 7 web app right out of the VS2022 template (no MVC template). No authentication was added. Only high level code in Program.cs. Then, I tried to run it, and no matter what I do, it always shows "Page not found" 404.

What am I missing here? I did everything "by the book"!

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

//builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
//{
//    options.RootDirectory = "/";
//});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

The Index.cshtml:

```
@page 
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace RazorPagesWebApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

both Index files are located in Pages folder:

[image]

Comment: After you remove the "//builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
//{
//    options.RootDirectory = "/";
//});"  , is the 404 error disappear ?

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you sure you're trying the right url? What does your `Properties/launchSettings.json` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by updating VS2022 to 17.8.1